# system of three equations with Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, systems-of-equations

First of - sorry for my English.

My math teacher gave me three tasks to complete, but I can't complete the second one.

Here is the system:
$$\begin{cases} x+y-z=3 \\ x-3y+2z=1 \\ 7x-4y+z=7\end{cases}$$

We have to complete them using Cramer's rule. Determinant result is 43 for me, but today when I asked teacher she said there should be 1. I can't figure it out. How it can be 1? It would be great if someone could explain how to get to 1 step by step.

Comment: Don't use images unless they can't be explained otherwise. And matrices definitely can be rendered here. Besides, we can't know where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient matrix for the system $$\begin{cases} x+y-z=3 \\ x-3y+2z=1 \\ 7x-4y+z=7\end{cases}$$ is $$\pmatrix{1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -3 & 2 \\ 7 & -4 & 1}$$

Let's find the determinant:

$$\begin{align}\left|\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -3 & 2 \\ 7 & -4 & 1\end{array}\right| &= \left|\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -4 & 3 \\ 0 & -11 & 8\end{array}\right| \\ &= \frac 13\left|\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -12 & 9 \\ 0 & -11 & 8\end{array}\right| \\ &= \frac 13\left|\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -11 & 8\end{array}\right| \\ &= -\frac 13\left|\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & -3\end{array}\right| \\ &= -\frac 13(1)(1)(-3) \\ &= 1\end{align}$$

---

**EDIT**: Here's the cofactor expansion method of finding the determinant.  I'll expand across the top row:

$$\begin{align}\left|\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -3 & 2 \\ 7 & -4 & 1\end{array}\right| &= (1)\left|\begin{array}{cc} -3 & 2 \\ -4 & 1\end{array}\right|-(1)\left|\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ 7 & 1\end{array}\right|+(-1)\left|\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -3 \\ 7 & -4\end{array}\right| \\ &= (1)[-3\cdot 1 - 2\cdot(-4)] -(1)[1\cdot 1 - 2\cdot 7]+(-1)[1\cdot(-4)-(-3\cdot 7)] \\ &= 5+13-17 \\ &=1\end{align}$$

Comment: We would use:  = 1*(-3)*1+1*2*7+1*(-4)*(-1)... to get the determinant. So I'm even more lost after what you showed..

Comment: Ah.  You haven't learned the relationship between the elementary row operations and the determinant are yet.  OK.  I'll edit in the cofactor expansion.  Give me a minute.

Comment: Yeah we have not :( Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Or [here's Sarrus's rule](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1*-3*1%2B1*2*7%2B-1*1*-4-%28-1*-3*7%29-%281*1*1%29-%281*2*-4%29).

Comment: Huge thanks! :) Now it makes sense!!!